# Problema haciendo json_decode en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un pequeño problema y es que cuando hago json_decode en el siguiente codigo realiza una petición ipv6 por lo cual no funciona.
Me gustaria hacerlo con curl y que realice una petición ipv4 (seria posible)

```
$long_url = "{$gen_url}/credentials.php?u=_{$altss}"; 
$api_token = $api_token;
$api_url = "{$api_url}{$api_token}&url={$long_url}";
$result = @json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url),TRUE);
if($result["status"] === 'error') {
echo $result["message"];
} else {
}
```

Comment: con el tercer parámetro de `file_get_contents` podés [forzar IPv4 creando un contexto bindeado a 0:0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php#118209)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `$api_url` antes del `json_decode`?

Comment: El api url es un link que contiene el código de la api en este caso https://clicksfly.com/api?api=